# How to prove that $\sin(180^\circ-\theta)=\sin\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Mi question is: How to prove $$\sin(180^\circ-\theta)=\sin\theta$$ ?

Here, sine is defined for any angle such as 'alpha'

This is the question mi college teacher asked me to derive it but i could not. plz help me. Iam 12 grade. thank you....

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin$?

Comment: Do you know how to expand the expression $\sin(a+b)$?

Comment: 'sin' is sine of any angle

Comment: I don't know. please help me

Comment: I believe Zev's question to you was: "What is the definition of $\sin\theta$? Given $\theta$ how do determine its sine. Is it the $y$-coordinate of a certain point on the unit circle, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By symmetry with respect to the vertical axis: reflect the line $OA$ forming the $\theta$ angle. The triangle $OAA'$ is isosceles, hence the $y$ axis is orthogonal to the base $AA'$ and the altitude is the sine. The reflected angle is $\pi-\theta$.

[image]

By a similar argument, $\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

$$
\sin(x-y) = \sin x\cos y-\cos x \sin y
$$

and

$\cos 180^\circ =-1$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\sin(A - B) = \sin(A)\cos(B) - \cos(A)\sin(B).$$
Then
$$\sin(180° - \theta) = \sin(180°)\cos(\theta) - \cos(180°)\sin(\theta).$$
Since $$\sin(180°) = 0\ \ \textrm{ and }\ \cos(180°) = -1,$$
we get
$$\sin(180° - \theta) = 0 - (-1)\sin(\theta) = \sin(\theta).$$

Answer (score 0):

We are going to need these two identities

$\sin\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \Big) = \cos(x)$

$\cos\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - x \Big) = \sin(x)$

Now here is the setup:

$\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - \Big[ \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \Big] \Big) = \cos\Big( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \Big)$

From here we have to use the fact that cosine is an even function, $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$:

$\cos\Big( \theta - \frac{\pi}{2} \Big) = \cos\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \Big) = \sin(\theta)$